# Getting Unexpected xpath results

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Here is the source xml: [xml](http://testvipd7.scene7.com/is/agm/papermusepress/HOL_12_F_green?&fmt=fxgraw)

This is the xml of an fxg file produced by Adobe.  The FXG document is valid xml, and it basically contains all the information for a document that can be edited.  This specific question pertains to text that can be changed within the FXG so that the content can change.

I'm tryng to grab all the RichText elements and attributes within that element that have an attribute of `s7:elementID` using xpath relative location.

The source XML only has three total `RichText` elements, with only two of them having a `s7:elementID`

```
<?php

$url = "http://testvipd7.scene7.com/is/agm/papermusepress/HOL_12_F_green?&fmt=fxgraw";    
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);       
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('default', 'http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('s7', 'http://ns.adobe.com/S7FXG/2008');
$textNode = $xml->xpath("//default:RichText/@s7:elementID");

print("<pre>".print_r($textNode,true)."</pre>");

?>
```

I got this far with help from another question. But the returned array is not what I was expecting.  setting the xpath as I did, I am expecting it to select all the `RichText` elements that have an `s7:elementID`, as well as the other attributes of that element.  However, it isn't grabbing any of the other attributes of those elements.  here is what it outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [elementID] => smalltext
                )

        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [elementID] => largetext
                )

        )

)
```

If I take the exact same php but change the xpath like so:

```
$textNode = $xml->xpath("//default:RichText");
```

I get this array result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 278.418
                    [y] => 115.542
                    [columnGap] => 18
                    [columnCount] => 1
                    [textAlign] => left
                    [fontFamily] => Trade Gothic LT Pro Bold Cn
                    [fontSize] => 11
                    [color] => #518269
                    [whiteSpaceCollapse] => preserve
                    [width] => 212.582
                    [height] => 33
                )

            [content] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [p] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [span] => Scott, Anna, and Conner
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [span] => and our little one on the way
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 278.998
                    [y] => 86.7168
                    [columnGap] => 18
                    [columnCount] => 1
                    [textAlign] => left
                    [fontFamily] => Bootstrap
                    [fontSize] => 19
                    [color] => #518269
                    [whiteSpaceCollapse] => preserve
                    [trackingRight] => 4%
                    [width] => 240
                    [height] => 29
                )

            [content] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [p] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [span] => THE JOHNSONS
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 278.418
                    [y] => 77.2373
                    [columnGap] => 0
                    [columnCount] => 1
                    [textAlign] => left
                    [fontFamily] => Trade Gothic LT Pro Bold Cn
                    [fontSize] => 11
                    [color] => #518269
                    [whiteSpaceCollapse] => preserve
                )

            [content] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [p] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [span] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => W
                                    [1] => ishing you the best this season.
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

If you notice, the first two array items don't even have the info for the `s7:elementID`, but they are the two that should.  The third does not have a `s7:elementID` by design.

Can anyone explain why I am getting these unexpected array results, with some attributes showing up, and others not?

**UPDATE**

Per dusan, i updated the php to:

`$textNode = $xml->xpath("//default:RichText[@s7:elementID]");`

Now the array only returns attributes of the element that do not have a prefix.  I need all attributes, prefix and not.

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 278.418
                    [y] => 115.542
                    [columnGap] => 18
                    [columnCount] => 1
                    [textAlign] => left
                    [fontFamily] => Trade Gothic LT Pro Bold Cn
                    [fontSize] => 11
                    [color] => #518269
                    [whiteSpaceCollapse] => preserve
                    [width] => 212.582
                    [height] => 33
                )

            [content] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [p] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [span] => Scott, Anna, and Conner
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [span] => and our little one on the way
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [x] => 278.998
                    [y] => 86.7168
                    [columnGap] => 18
                    [columnCount] => 1
                    [textAlign] => left
                    [fontFamily] => Bootstrap
                    [fontSize] => 19
                    [color] => #518269
                    [whiteSpaceCollapse] => preserve
                    [trackingRight] => 4%
                    [width] => 240
                    [height] => 29
                )

            [content] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [p] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [span] => THE JOHNSONS
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**UPDATE 2**

changing the php to this seems to get all the attributes, both default and with the `s7` prefix:

```
<?php
$url = "http://testvipd7.scene7.com/is/agm/papermusepress/HOL_12_F_green?&fmt=fxgraw";    
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);       
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('default', 'http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('s7', 'http://ns.adobe.com/S7FXG/2008');
$textNode = $xml->xpath("//default:RichText[@s7:elementID]"); // //default:RichText[@s7:elementID]/@*

function pr($var) { print '<pre>'; print_r($var); print '</pre>'; }


foreach($textNode as $node){
    pr($node->attributes('http://ns.adobe.com/S7FXG/2008'));
    pr($node->attributes());
}
?>
```

And the XML Result:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [caps] => none
            [colorName] => 
            [colorValue] => #518269
            [colorspace] => rgb
            [elementID] => smalltext
            [fill] => true
            [fillOverprint] => false
            [firstBaselineOffset] => ascent
            [joints] => miter
            [maxFontSize] => 11
            [miterLimit] => 4
            [referencePoint] => inherit
            [rowCount] => 1
            [rowGap] => 18
            [rowMajorOrder] => true
            [stroke] => false
            [strokeOverprint] => false
            [warpBend] => 0.5
            [warpDirection] => horizontal
            [warpHorizontalDistortion] => 0
            [warpStyle] => none
            [warpVerticalDistortion] => 0
            [weight] => 1
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [x] => 278.418
            [y] => 115.542
            [columnGap] => 18
            [columnCount] => 1
            [textAlign] => left
            [fontFamily] => Trade Gothic LT Pro Bold Cn
            [fontSize] => 11
            [color] => #518269
            [whiteSpaceCollapse] => preserve
            [width] => 212.582
            [height] => 33
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [caps] => none
            [colorName] => 
            [colorValue] => #518269
            [colorspace] => rgb
            [elementID] => largetext
            [fill] => true
            [fillOverprint] => false
            [firstBaselineOffset] => ascent
            [joints] => miter
            [maxFontSize] => 19
            [miterLimit] => 4
            [referencePoint] => inherit
            [rowCount] => 1
            [rowGap] => 18
            [rowMajorOrder] => true
            [stroke] => false
            [strokeOverprint] => false
            [warpBend] => 0.5
            [warpDirection] => horizontal
            [warpHorizontalDistortion] => 0
            [warpStyle] => none
            [warpVerticalDistortion] => 0
            [weight] => 1
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [x] => 278.998
            [y] => 86.7168
            [columnGap] => 18
            [columnCount] => 1
            [textAlign] => left
            [fontFamily] => Bootstrap
            [fontSize] => 19
            [color] => #518269
            [whiteSpaceCollapse] => preserve
            [trackingRight] => 4%
            [width] => 240
            [height] => 29
        )

)
```

now that it is able to retrieve all the attributes of the `RichText` element.  How can I store certain attributes as a specific variable?  For example, how can I set a variable for the `s7:elementID` and the `fontSize` attributes?

Comment: Have you tried: `//default:RichText[@s7:elementID]/@*` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `//default:RichText/@s7:elementID` you are selecting `elementID` attributes, not the `RichText` tag.

Use this:

```
$textNode = $xml->xpath("//default:RichText[@s7:elementID]");
```

**Update:** The [SimpleXMLElement::attributes docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) says that:

> SimpleXML has made a rule of adding iterative properties to most methods. They cannot be viewed using var_dump() or anything else which can examine objects.

So `print_r` is not showing to you all the information. Try getting the attributes using their namespace:

```
foreach($textNode as $node){
    var_dump($node->attributes('http://ns.adobe.com/S7FXG/2008'));
}
```

Comment: this is making a little more sense now.  but my last issue is that it is not grabbing any attributes in the `RichText` element that have a prefix of `s7:`.  It is only getting the attributes that do not have a prefix.  I updated the main post to show the array.  Any idea why it would be doing that?  I need all the attributes that have a prefix or not.

Comment: I find it weird that xpath is referencing all `RichText` elements that have `s7:elementID`, but then it doesn't even output that attribute in the array..?

Comment: i tried your new suggestion.  now it is only outputting the attributes with `s7:` it ignores all attributes with no prefix..

Comment: Yes, to get attributes without prefix use `$node->attributes()`. Have you tried Dimitre Novatchev's suggestion (look at your question's comment)?

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and now I can see all attributes for the `RichText` elements that have a `s7:elementID` attribute.  I updated the question with one last extension... how can I make specific attributes into a variable?